# MeshLab Error: Export to Sketchfab - API TOKEN

Tags: api, token, meshlab

I'm having problems with the Export to Sketchfab tool in the new version of MeshLab.
When I try to upload my 3D model in Sketchfab MeshLab shows me this erro message:

*Failure of filter: "Export to SketchFab"
Please set in the MeshLab preferences your private API token thst you can find on the SketchFab Password Settings*

But that is what I exactly do.

Anyone has the same problem? Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should copy the your private API token from the sketchfab website (click on Profile Menu (the Avatar) -> Settings -> [password and API](https://sketchfab.com/settings/password) ) open the MeshLab preferences panel, double click on the MeshLab parameter called '*MeshLab::Plugins::Sketchfab keycode*' and paste it in the empty text field.
You should paste it exactly as without adding any space. Press the save button, close the preference dialog and try again to export the model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice Aloopinglcon! I did it but the problem continues. It's a pity. I will upload my model trough other option.